# All of a sudden Ubuntu says router is out of range

Tags: wireless

My PC has been connecting well though my Linksys router and D-Link adapter. But today the PC will not connect and tells me that it is "out of range." All previous discussions here seem to deal with something that has been changed. But I have not changed anything. Ubuntu has has just quit. Two iPhones, an iPad, and a Nook have no problem connecting with the Internet.

Comment: Reboot the router；reboot the PC.

Comment: Can you use "connect to a hidden wifi" to connect to this router?